# Checkbox Data Dynamically Save to Database on Click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I need some js/ajax/jquery script saving data to database dynamically when I check the check-box.
the checkboxes at the moment or loaded in next to records and change the variable in the database depending if its checked or not.but i have to reload the page after i select one to save it to the database. i can do everything else but understand how to implement the ajax to this so i don't have to submit the query and refresh the page every time. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    <form name="form1aa" method="post" action="process.php?fn=<? echo $rows['first']; ?>&class=<?php echo $rows['class']; ?>&last=<?php echo $rows['last']; ?>
&model=<?php echo $rows['model']; ?>&cas=<?php echo $rows['cases']; ?>&upid=<?php echo $id; ?>&group=1" id="form1a" >

    <select name="type" onchange=" fill_damage (document.form1aa.type.selectedIndex); ">
    <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
    <option value="Software">Software</option>
    </select>
    <select name="damage">
    </select>
    <input type=text name="comment"  placeholder="Comments Box">
    <input type=text name="cost"  placeholder="Cost">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="Save">
    </form>

<?php

//Job Status
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
if(isset($_POST['activate'])?$activate = $_POST["activate"]:$deactivate = $_POST["deactivate"])
$id = "('" . implode( "','", $checkbox ) . "');" ;
$sql="UPDATE repairs SET status = '".(isset($activate)?'Completed':'In Progress')."' WHERE id=$id" ;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
//End Job Status

//Payment Status
if(isset($_POST['paycheck'])){$paycheck = $_POST['paycheck'];
if(isset($_POST['paid'])?$paid = $_POST["paid"]:$unpaid = $_POST["unpaid"])
$id = "('" . implode( "','", $paycheck ) . "');" ;
$sql="UPDATE repairs SET paid = '".(isset($paid)?'Paid':'Unpaid')."' WHERE id=$id" ;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
//End Payment Status

//Return Status
if(isset($_POST['retcheck'])){$retcheck = $_POST['retcheck'];
if(isset($_POST['ret'])?$ret = $_POST["ret"]:$unret = $_POST["unret"])
$id = "('" . implode( "','", $retcheck ) . "');" ;
$sql="UPDATE repairs SET ret = '".(isset($ret)?'Retuned':'In Office')."' WHERE id=$id" ;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
//End Return Status
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
if(isset($_POST['all'])){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
}
if(isset($_POST['tpc'])){
    $sql="select * from $tbl_name WHERE class LIKE '1%'";
}
if(isset($_POST['drc'])){
    $sql="select * from $tbl_name WHERE class LIKE 'D%'";
}
if(isset($_POST['bsc'])){
    $sql="select * from $tbl_name WHERE class LIKE 'B%'";
}

$result=mysql_query($sql);

?>
<form  name="frmactive" method="post" action="">
                <input name="activate" type="submit" id="activate" value="Complete Job" />
                <input name="paid" type="submit" id="Payment" value="Payment Status" />
                <input name="ret" type="submit" id="ret" value="Returned 2 Student" />
                <br />

<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show Extra</a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">
<br />
                <input name="unret" type="submit" id="unret" value="In Office" />
                <input name="unpaid" type="submit" id="unpaid" value="Not Paid" />
                <input name="deactivate" type="submit" id="deactivate" value="In Progress" /></div>

<table width="1000" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<thead>
<th width="67" align="center"><strong>Start Date</strong></th>
<th width="50" align="center"><strong>Cases</strong></th>
<th width="34" align="center"><strong>Type</strong></th>
<th width="120" align="center"><strong>Damage</strong></th>
<th width="31" align="center"><strong>Comment</strong></th>
<th width="31" align="center"><strong>Cost</strong></th>
<th width="90" align="center"><strong>Payment Status</strong></th>
<th width="100" align="center"><strong>Returned 2 Student</strong></th>
<th width="100" align="center"><strong>Job Status</strong></th>
</thead>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>

<td><? echo $rows['start']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['cases']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['type']; ?></td>
<td width="70"><? echo $rows['damage']; ?></td>
<td width="70"><? echo $rows['comment']; ?></td>
<td><? echo "$"; echo $rows['cost']; ?></td>

<!--Payment Display(Start)-->
<?php 
        if($rows['paid']=="Paid")
        {
                ?>
                    <td><input name="paycheck[]" type="checkbox" id="paycheck[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
                <? echo $rows['paid'];?>
                    </td>
                    <?
}

        if($rows['paid']=="Unpaid")
        {
              ?>
                    <td width="21"><input name="paycheck[]" type="checkbox" id="paycheck[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
                <? echo $rows['paid']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <?
}
if($rows['ret']==""){
    ?>
    <td width="50">No Data</td>
    <?
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the code that you have tried ?

Comment: heres the code that i have at the moment i just havent been able to get my head around using ajax with it.

Comment: You will need to change your logic, check my answer to have an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it with jQuery, a simple example could be:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk">
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Sugar">
<input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="Chocolate">
```

**JS:**

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
   var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
   if(checked){
      var value = $(this).val();
      $.post('file.php', { value:value }, function(data){
          // data = 0 - means that there was an error
          // data = 1 - means that everything is ok
          if(data == 1){
             // Do something or do nothing :-)
             alert('Data was saved in db!');
          }
      });
   }
});
```

**PHP: file.php**

```
<?php
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['value'])) {

    // db connection
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$link) {
       // error happened
       print(0);
    }
    mysql_select_db('mydb');

    // sanitize the value
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);

    // start the query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ('$value')";

    // check if the query was executed
    if(mysql_query($sql, $link)){
       // everything is Ok, the data was inserted
       print(1);    
    } else {
       // error happened
       print(0);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: hey im sorry but i have only had minimal expernece with jquery do you have the code on hand to pull it in sorry about this

Comment: The code I gave you do what you need, to start go to jquery.com, download the jquery.js file and import it in your script tag in html. Finally, put the JS code I gave you inside this $(document).ready(function(){ //Paste the code here }); Thats all, you can test now

Comment: i have done all of that and the code doesnt do anything im sorry about being a pest.

Comment: did u upload the php file too? try to test all the code snippets i gave u in a separate project, i tested and works

Comment: umm i  put the html and java script in one page called checkt.html and the php in file.php ? is that correct

Comment: thats with the jquery in the script tag like this <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js">

Answer (score 1):

Simple put...

```
$('input:checkbox').click( function() {
  clicked = $(this).attr('checked');
  if (clicked) {
    /* AJAX the server to tell them it was clicked. */ }
  else {
    /* AJAX the server to tell them it was unclicked. */ } } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I can make this even simpler.  first, you need to ad a checkbox!!

```
<form name="form1aa" method="post" action="process.php?fn=<? echo $rows['frist']; ?>&class=<?php echo $rows['class']; ?>&last=<?php echo $rows['last']; ?>
&model=<?php echo $rows['model']; ?>&cas=<?php echo $rows['cases']; ?>&upid=<?php echo $id; ?>&group=1" id="form1a" >

    <select name="type" onchange="fill_damage(document.form1aa.type.selectedIndex);">
    <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
    <option value="Software">Software</option>
    </select>
    <select name="damage">
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="comment"  placeholder="Comments Box">
    <input type="text" name="cost"  placeholder="Cost">
    <input type="checkbox" name="somecheck" onchange="if(this.checked)document.form1aa.submit()">Check this to Save.
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="Save">
    </form>


<script type="javascript>
//another function that works for onchange="dosubmit(this)"
//IF you put it after the form.
function dosubmit(el) {
    if (el.checked) {
        document.form1aa.submit();
    }
}
</script>
```

get rid of the spaces in your onchange events where possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamic checkbox list and you want to dynamically save the clicked one to database or inserting the unchecked one, here how to do that:

**Html/PHP**

```
       <?php
        // $checklists are models that I am getting from db
        $checklists = CheckList::getCheckLists(3);
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($checklists as $checklist) {
            $isChecked = $checklist->getAnswer($requestID, $checklist->primaryKey);
            $checked = $isChecked ? "checked" : "";
            echo '<li>';
            echo "<input id='{$checklist->primaryKey}' 
            name='{$checklist->primaryKey}'  type='checkbox' {$checked} 
            value='{$isChecked}' data-request-id='{$requestID}'> 
            $checklist->check_list_text";
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        ?>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var checked = checkbox.prop('checked');
    var checklistId = checkbox.attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        url:"<?= Url::to(['default/add-checklist-answer']) ?>",
        // I don't need to write the type here because I am using Yii Framework
        // type: 'post',
        data: {
            checklistId: checklistId,
            requestId: checkbox.data('request-id'),
            checked: checked
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            console.log(data.firstMessage)
        },
        error: function(data) {
            // alert(data);
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

***I hope it will work for MVC users.***