# Dynamically added checkboxes are not saving

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I was trying to add the rows dynamically. It seems to be all the data is  saving on server side except checkboxes.

```
            <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">
              <input name="F_02_0080_2" id="F_02_0080_2" class="" type="checkbox">          
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">
              <input name="F_02_0090_2" id="F_02_0090_2" class="" type="checkbox">
            </td>
```

This is the structure  when I add a dynamic checkbox.
Here is my javascript (Removed unwanted functions, so please ignore if definition of a func not found.):

```
ihtx.prvl_unlisted_securities_0101_h250527 = {
    createnew:function(parent_tr){
          var _this = ihtx.prvl_unlisted_securities_0101_h250527;
          var clonned_tr = parent_tr.clone() 
          _this.set_after(parent_tr, clonned_tr);
          _this.update_row_attributes(clonned_tr, parent_tr.index()/2);
          _this.set_blank_row(clonned_tr);
          $(clonned_tr).find("td:eq(1)").html(element);
          $(clonned_tr).nextAll(".sortable-ihtx").each(function(i, elm){
          var rowindex =  (clonned_tr.index()/2 +i);
                _this.update_row_attributes($(this), rowindex);
                _this.update_row_attributes($(this).next(), rowindex);
          });
    },
    set_after:function(row1, row2){
       // One row is a combination of two `tr`s
       // only first tr have the checkboxes
        var last_row = row1[1];
        $(last_row).after(row2);
    },
    update_row_attributes:function(oldrow, index_to_set){
        var _this = ihtx.prvl_unlisted_securities_0101_h250527;
        $(oldrow).children().find("input[type='text'], textarea,  input[type='checkbox']").each(function(i, elm){
        if($(this).is("[type='text']"))$(this).inputmask();
        if(isFloat(index_to_set))index_to_set =index_to_set - 0.5;
        _this.set_elm_attributes($(this), index_to_set);
    });
    _this.update_display_order(oldrow, index_to_set);
   },
   set_elm_attributes:function(elm, oldindex){
       var _this = ihtx.prvl_unlisted_securities_0101_h250527;
       var attributes = elm.attr();
       $.each(attributes, function(key, val){
        if($.inArray(key, ["name", "id", "class"]) != -1){
            $newattr = _this.get_new_attribute_name(key, val, oldindex);
            if(key == "class"){
                $class = elm.attr("class")
                $newattr = $class.replace(elm.attr("name"),                                              _this.get_new_attribute_name("class", elm.attr("name"), oldindex));
            }
            elm.attr(key, $newattr);
        } 
    });
}
},
set_blank_row:function(row){
    $(row).children().find("input[type='text'], textarea, input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
        $(this).val("");
        if($(this).is(':checkbox')){
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
         }

    });
},
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkbox Data Dynamically Save to Database on Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407704/checkbox-data-dynamically-save-to-database-on-click)

Comment: @dcc: but I can't use ajax to save, particularly for this form. There are lots of things that needs to be done manually if I use that.

Comment: Are the added checkboxes inside the form? When a form is submitted, there's no difference between static elements and dynamic elements, it just uses whatever is currently in the DOM.

Comment: Seems like you are passing all the checkboxes as the same `name`.. You will either have to pass them with individual names or as an array `F_02_0090_2[]`

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted How are they the same name? `0080` != `0090`.

Comment: How are you testing that the checkboxes are being saved? You're not giving them any value, so the values will be empty strings on the server.

Comment: Also notice that a checkbox value is not sent if it is not checked.. You can try to add a piece of javascript that can add a `false` value to the unchecked boxes

Comment: @Barmar My mistake.. :) Didn't notice..

Comment: @Barmar: checkboxes lies within the form.
--You're not giving them any value, so the values will be empty strings on the server. 
<<<< Yes, This is what happening.

Comment: So the answer should be obvious: give them values.

Comment: @Barmar: Okay, Let me  try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments of @Barmar, I should do the following changes:

```
   set_blank_row:function(row){
      $(row).children().find("input[type='text'], textarea,input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
      $(this).val("");
      if($(this).is(':checkbox')){
        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            var clicked = $(this).attr('checked');
            if(clicked){
                $(this).attr('value', 'on');
            }else{
                $(this).removeAttr('value');
            }
       }

     });
}
```